# mel2pyStr fails when selecting group of objects

Tags: maya, mel, pymel

I am trying to convert a bunch of MEL code into Python in Maya 2015 like this:

```
mel2py.mel2pyStr(melCmd,pymelNamespace='pm', verbosity=4, forceCompatibility=True)
```

where `melCmd` is a multi-line code.

But it fails when converting the following line:

```
select -add pPipe1.e[2500:2549] ;
```

The error states that `:` is unexpected:

```
p_expression - line 12
original token:
['None', '2500']
result:
2500
# Result : <Token @ 0x18faa7a2678> ('2500')
# 
# State  : 271
# Stack  : translation_unit ID command_statement_input_list ID LBRACKET expression . LexToken(COLON,u':',12,407)
# ERROR: Error  : translation_unit ID command_statement_input_list ID LBRACKET expression . LexToken(COLON,u':',12,407)
# 
# State  : 0
# Stack  : . $end
# ERROR: Error  : . $end
# Error: MelParseError: file C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2015\Python\lib\site-packages\pymel\tools\mel2py\melparse.py line 2940: Errors:
line 12 (COLON): : #
```

I am trying to select (and then modify) several edges at once. How should I do it in Python? Why does mel2py fail?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Here is the full MEL code:

```
CreatePolygonPipe;
setToolTo CreatePolyPipeCtx;
setAttr "polyPipe1.thickness" 0.6;
polyPipe -ch on -o on -r 4.343087 -h 4.057391 -t 0.6 ;
// Result: pPipe1 polyPipe1 // 
select -addFirst polyPipe1 ;
setAttr "polyPipe1.subdivisionsAxis" 50;
setAttr "polyPipe1.subdivisionsHeight" 37.4;
setAttr "polyPipe1.subdivisionsHeight" 50;
select -r pPipe1.e[2546] ;
select -r pPipe1.e[2546] ;
select -add pPipe1.e[2500:2549] ;
select -tgl pPipe1.e[10] ;
select -add pPipe1.e[0:49] ;
ScaleToolWithSnapMarkingMenu;
dR_ScaleToolMarkingMenuPopDown;
scale -r -p -4.723702cm 1.014348cm -1.380022cm 1.054283 1.054283 1.054283 ;
select -r pPipe1.e[2498] ;
select -add pPipe1.e[2450:2499] ;
select -tgl pPipe1.e[61] ;
select -add pPipe1.e[50:99] ;
scale -r -p -4.723702cm 1.014348cm -1.380022cm 1.025089 1.025089 1.025089 ;
select -r pPipe1.e[2556] ;
select -add pPipe1.e[2550:2599] ;
select -tgl pPipe1.e[5096] ;
select -add pPipe1.e[5050:5099] ;
scale -r -p -4.723702cm 1.014348cm -1.380022cm 0.960232 0.960232 0.960232 ;
select -r pPipe1.e[2644] ;
select -add pPipe1.e[2600:2649] ;
select -tgl pPipe1.e[5044] ;
select -add pPipe1.e[5000:5049] ;
scale -r -p -4.723702cm 1.014348cm -1.380022cm 0.981905 0.981905 0.981905 ;
select -r pPipe1.e[2546] ;
select -add pPipe1.e[2500:2549] ;
TranslateToolWithSnapMarkingMenu;
dR_TranslateToolMarkingMenuPopDown;
move -r 0 -0.07989 0 ;
select -r pPipe1.e[46] ;
select -add pPipe1.e[0:49] ;
move -r 0 0.07989 0 ;
select -d pPipe1.e[0:49] ;
select -r pPipe1 ;
select -cl  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically its crashing on string and I am not if this is a expected behavior, this is how you can fix it

```
melCmd = 'select -add "pPipe1.e[2500:2549]";'
```